# Eclipse Axis2 Service Archiver Plugin Problem

Tags: web-services, eclipse-plugin, apache-axis

My Eclipse Axis2 Service Archiver plugin is no longer working properly. I have used it to build several .aar files but now when i open the plugin I only get blank gray screens. I've tried deleting the org.apache.axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin folder from my workspace plugins directory and even removing the org.apache.axis2.eclipse.service.plugin_1.6.0.jar and reinstalling but I still get the same blank screens. I'm using Eclipse Indigo now, I even went back to Eclipse Helios and the same problem occurred. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.factory.OMLinkedListMetaFactory

Looks like you need axiom library in your cp.

I used to have the same problem, I solved it by going to Axis Runtime configuration under Eclipse Settings then remove the path to axis2 runtime. Apply and re-set the runtime path. Apply and try again to use your plugin.

Answer (score 2):

This might help: 
1) Shut down eclipse
2) Change into the workspace plugins folder (something like:
workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.apache2.eclipse.service.plugin)
3) Delete the file there (called dialog-settings or something).
4) Then restart eclipse and try if it works.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution occasionally. When you get a grey dialog, maximize it, and it will display correctly

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had extracted the jar for the plugin into the *plugins* folder in the eclipse installation directory. I moved them to the *dropins* folder in the eclipse installation directory and restarted eclipse. It is working properly now.

UPDATE: The problem is back. I found it is printing an exception in the workspace log:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis2.tool.service.eclipse.ui.ServiceXMLGenerationPage.updateTable(ServiceXMLGenerationPage.java:241)
at org.apache.axis2.tool.service.eclipse.ui.ServiceXMLGenerationPage.createControl(ServiceXMLGenerationPage.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:736)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.setWizard(WizardDialog.java:1183)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1242)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.access$4(WizardDialog.java:1239)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$8.run(WizardDialog.java:1228)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1226)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:915)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:277)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.factory.OMLinkedListMetaFactory
at org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getMetaFactory(OMAbstractFactory.java:139)
at org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory(OMAbstractFactory.java:152)
at com.gvr.fms.devcomm.interfacelayer.DevcommWebService.<clinit>(DevcommWebService.java:32)
... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.factory.OMLinkedListMetaFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getMetaFactory(OMAbstractFactory.java:133)
... 59 more
```